# Is $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$ if $A$ and $B$ are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices is $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$?

I thought because, $AB + BA = AB - AB = 0$.

Comment: Consider matrices that are all zero except the entry in the top-left position. They will behave like numbers, which don't satisfy that in general.

Comment: Or just consider $1\times1$ matrices.

Comment: That works only for certain cases, anti-commutative matrices.

Comment: Why did you think that $AB+BA=AB-AB$? This is quite not true! You can see this by picking at random two 2-by-2 matrices $A$ and $B$ and computing both sides of the equation.

Comment: I'm not sure why did I think AB+BA=AB−AB :) I must have confused it with something else but I'm not sure what

Comment: You are confusing the product $AB$ with the commutator $[A,B] = AB - BA$.

Answer (score 7):

$$(A+B)^2 = (A+B)(A+B) = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2 \neq A^2 + B^2$$

$(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$ if and only if $AB + BA = 0 \iff AB = -BA$, but this is not true in general.

Comment: Moreover, you proved OP's statement is true iff $AB = -BA$.

Comment: @gt6989b I'm going to specify that, even though it should be clear. Thanks for the input! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Consider the $1\times 1$ matrices.  What do we know from algebra?

In fact this is  called the "Freshman's Dream" and it appears that Kaj_H is trying to generalize this result for matrices (larger than $1\times 1$).

So in general if the characteristic of the field is $p$ (a prime) and the matrices are commutative then

$$(A+B)^{p^n} = A^{p^n} + p*Stuff + B^{p^n}$$

but then $p*Stuff=0$ because the characteristic of the field is $p$, so 
$$(A+B)^{p^n} = A^{p^n} + B^{p^n}$$

But this is a general group structure statement, we just need conditions on the field for which matrices are defined over.  This is particularly simple to see if the matrices $A,B$ are diagonal, it reduces to the $1\times 1$ case for each (diagonal) entry.

Comment: I was about to post "Have you thought about $1 \times 1$-matrices??".

Answer (score 4):

No this is not true. Consider
$$
\left[\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}+ \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\right]^2 \neq \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}^2 + \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}^2 
$$
Note also that it is not in general true that $AB = -BA$. Consider the case where $A = B$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not the case.  However, you can make it work with certain prior stipulations.  For example, $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$ if both of the following properties hold:

1. $A, B \in M(2, \mathbb{Z_2})$
2. $A, B$ are both diagonal matrices or both matrices with zeros everywhere except in the top right corner.

Comment: (2) seems wrong; see Thomas' answer ($I$ is diagonal...)

Comment: Note that I am working in $\mathbb{Z_2}$.  Stipulation 1 is coupled with stipulation 2.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: Also, $A$ and $B$ don't have to be diagonal; they just need to anticommute, which in $\Bbb Z_2$ is the same as commuting. Thus only one needs to be diagonal.

Comment: Sure.  I admit that my properties are perhaps more restrictive than they necessarily need to be.  I was simply trying to provide a concrete example that OP could study.