# Proofs of matrix properties

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

Prove of refute: If $A$ is any $n\times n$ matrix then $(I-A)^{2}=I-2A+A^{2}$.

$(I-A)^{2} = (I-A)(I-A) = I - A - A + A^{2} = I - (A+A) + A\cdot A$ only holds if the matrix addition $A+A$ holds and the matrix multiplication $A\cdot A$ holds. We know $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix hence both matrix addition and multiplication are valid hence $(I-A)^{2}=I-2A+A^{2}$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Comment: It is correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct and indeed multiplication and addition are well defined. The more interesting question is: "Is the following true?"

$$(A+B)^2= A^2+2AB+B^2$$

The answer is true provided $A$ and $B$ commute.

$$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$$

A related interesting question:
[Is $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$ if $A$ and $B$ are matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745667/is-ab2-a2-b2-if-a-and-b-are-matrices/745903#745903)

Answer (score 1):

It's correct because $I$ and $A$ commute.

In general, the binomial theorem and all combinatorial formulas for expressions like $(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n)^m$ and even other formulas like $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$ that hold for real numbers remain valid as long as the matrices involved commute with each other.